# SQL queries Is there any website where I get to build tables and test SQL queries?

Tags: sql

Is there any website where I get to build tables and test SQL queries? 
I have 3 tables and would like to execute some SQL statement but I wanna make sure the queries is correct. I want to see the output. 
Thank you for your help ?

Comment: Have you tried searching in Google/Bing?. I just tried and searching `test sql online` gives you good results.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this website for testing SQL queries

```
http://sqlfiddle.com/
```

you can choose from MySQL, Oracle, Postgre, and MSSQL